# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext drawInRect inaccurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, drawing, uigraphicscontext

I'm using this method to compress `UIImage`

```
if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio)
        {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio)
        {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
    }
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But for some `UIImage`, at the bottom of the of them, there is a 1 pixel white line. **Any suggestions on what could be the cause?**
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you're working with CGFloats and you're multiplying/dividing them and this results in a non-integral coordinates.

Line

```
actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
```

and

```
actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
```

may cause a non integral coordinate. Use `ceilf` or `floorf` or `roundf` to remedy this. E.g.

```
actualWidth = ceilf(imgRatio * actualWidth);
actualHeight = ceilf(imgRatio * actualHeight);
```

What happens without it

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
```

may actually be `(0,0,24.33, 24.33)`
You may actually be drawing a rect of this size, but image has to have a 
round number of pixels for height and width, so Apple probably rounds the rect up to create the image context.

But then they probably draw it using antialiasing, so it really visually looks like non-integral pixels. And that's why you get the white line and possibly a loss of quality too.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed respond! I suspected that behavior, tho i not near my computer to check it! Just a small question if i may : In general, it is possible to draw in  disround/ not primary number, as for (100.56, 34.6)? Or apple API will automatically round it(in this case, I don't see possible solution)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Adding ceil solved the problem, amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Even if you could draw like this, there's no way of displaying it on the device. The best the device can do is to antialias the whole picture - which makes it super blurry - you don't want that.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you so much!